# tar every subfolder named X in a bash file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tar

I have a folder that contains many folders and my wordpresses sites.

At the same folder i need to catch up the "uploads" subfolder and tar it named by its site.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Have you tried anything for this?

Comment: yes, but nothing until now...

Comment: If you've attempted to write a script to do this for you *show us* the script.

Comment: I have many doubts. First of all:

for d in var/www/*/htdocs/wp-content/uploads; do

 XXXXX

done

i need to get the folder name in a string to save the file later. So i need the substring of the folder. For ex.:

/var/www/site.com/htdocs/wp-content/uploads

I need to get the "site" name.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do the trick?

```
find /var/www -name uploads -a -type d | awk -F '/' '{ system("tar -czvf "$3".tar "$0) }'
```

The find command lists all the directories named upload under /var/www.
That's piped to awk, which splits it using the slash and runs tar. The third field is used as the file name and the whole string as the target for the tar.

Comment: This assumes, from your comments above, that you're dealing with `/var/www/sitename/htdocs/wp-content/uploads` and that there are no spaces in filenames.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me: `tar -cvf thisstuff.tar */uploads/*`

Comment: That should work but i need to name the file. In this way i wouldnt have the name of the site in the file.